# list of Employee having 2 products

Tags: sql, teradata, teradatasql

Can someone help here.

I have table employee. I want to find out list of employees having 2 products(P1,P2).

```
Emp_id    Prd_id
  E1         P1
  E1         P2
  E2         P1
  E2         P2
  E2         P3
  E3         P1
  E3         P3
  E4         P1
  E4         P2
```

So, I want output as

```
Emp_id
  E1
  E4
```

Comment: Okay, so what problem are you facing? Do you know how to count in SQL? Do you know how to count per employee? What is stopping you to write the query?

Comment: You mean only emp_ids that have **both** p1 and p2?

Comment: Excatly (P1,P2) or at least? Are (Emp_id, Prd_id) unique?

Comment: Yes exactly p1 and p2..Emp_id and prd_id are not unique

Comment: Yes Andrew.....

Comment: I can see a possible solution using string aggregation here -  `xmlagg` would seem to be Teradata's equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT emp_id
FROM employee
GROUP BY emp_id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN prd_id 'p1' THEN 1 END) > 0 -- p1 exists
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN prd_id 'p2' THEN 1 END) > 0 -- p2 exists
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN prd_id NOT IN ('p1', 'p2') THEN 1 END) = 0 -- but not other
```

Easier to extend to a larger number of products:

```
SELECT emp_id
FROM 
 ( -- get a unique list first
   SELECT DISTINCT emp_id, prd_id
   FROM employee
 ) AS dt
GROUP BY emp_id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN prd_id IN ('p1', 'p2') THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement is to find employees with any two products, you could use a `having` condition to count them:

```sql
SELECT   emp_id
FROM     employees
GROUP BY emp_id
HAVING   COUNT(*) = 2
```

If those products must be p1 and p2, you could add another condition on that:

```sql
SELECT   emp_id
FROM     employees
GROUP BY emp_id
HAVING   COUNT(*) = 2 AND
         COUNT(CASE WHEN prd_id IN ('p1', 'p2') THEN 1 END) = 2
```

Comment: Thanks Mureinik...
I was exactly looking for 2nd scenario

Comment: If the table doesn't contain duplicate rows for this (subset of) columns. More reliable way would be to do conditional aggregation per value and check if each of them is `> 0`